# High process memory when using Syncfusion's Charts in UWP during the screensaver/screen-off

Tags: c#, memory, charts, uwp, syncfusion

I have a small UWP app that reads data in real-time and displays it on `Syncfusion (v17.3460.0.14) SfChart`. Everything seemed to run fine but I left it overnight and it was using over `8Gb` of memory in the morning (and was frozen)!
Upon debugging it seems that when the screensaver kicks in, and presumably when the screen goes to sleep, the process memory starts slowly increasing, reaching GBs in a few hours; when the screensaver is then dismissed the memory usage returns to its normal expected level (`120MB process/80MB hea`p).
If I leave it running while I'm using the computer there is no problem.

I have reduced the code to a small example. Normally data would come from a `web API`. Removing the data-binding from the ItemsSource property of the FastLineSeries causes the problem to disappear.

```cs
public class DataPoint
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public long? AttainableRate { get; set; }
}

private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> Data { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();

public GraphPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    _timer.Tick += this.Timer_Tick;
    _timer.Start();
}

private async void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var ran = new Random();
    Data.Add(new DataPoint
    {
        Timestamp = now,
        AttainableRate = ran.Next(8000, 10000),
    });
}
```

```xml
<sf:SfChart>
    <sf:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
        <sf:DateTimeAxis RangePadding="Additional" Interval="10" IntervalType="Minutes" SmallTicksPerInterval="10" />
    </sf:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
    <sf:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
        <sf:NumericalAxis Header="Bandwidth (Kbps)" Minimum="0" Maximum="11000" Interval="1000" />
    </sf:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
    <sf:FastLineSeries Label=" Max. Attainable Rate (Kbps)"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Data}" XBindingPath="Timestamp" 
        YBindingPath="AttainableRate"/>
</sf:SfChart>
```

Here's a [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=11PFf2wDxfnwa_ULlO_r14RX_Gbdy6BZq) of a short example. At this point, the application has been running for about 30 minutes and the screensaver is on. Just before the rise (and the first snapshot) is when the screensaver was disabled.

**So, is this a problem with my code or a bug in Syncfusion or some other dotnet/UWP quirk?**